# Uploading Extension Marketplace

Tags: magento2, marketplace

with my company, we are trying to upload our extension to Magento 2 Marketplace. At the moment it works properly but only downloadable from our site. When I've tried to submit it, the first problem appears - different structure ( composer.json not found), it looks like package for upload should contain only module directory ("integration") without Vendor directory, but is it correct? Without vendor directory, every path in classes will crash... How does it work? Maybe marketplace generates it dynamically or something?

I was looking for help on official sites but without success...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is detailed official guide about how to properly pack and submit Magento 2 Extension to Marketplace http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html